# Content Grouping (not set) issue in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I want to try content grouping in Google Analytics. I have entered a couple of URLs in "Group Using Rule Definition" in Google Analytics and I have saved it without any error.

But when I try it in "Behavior" flow, its giving me "(not set)". Can anyone help me out how to deal with it? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!!

Comment: Perhaps your problem comes from the fact that content groups are not applied retroactively to the data? This information will only be available for the new visits.

Comment: is this a question about the website?  if so its not programing related and probably doesn't belong on stack.  If it is programing related ie the API then you need to post some code please.

Answer (score 0):

[This explanation from Google covers it briefly](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2853563?hl=en)

But the key point is

> (not set) is the collection of pages that are not assigned to any group.

If you assign more content groups you should see a reduction in "(not set)" in reports.

Answer (score 0):

If you are entering full URLs in the Group Using Rule Definition area, then you are creating groups of 1 page each.

A better rule is to use something like "starts with" with a partial url "/foo" to group all pages that start with "/foo", or similar logic.

Each content item is placed in the first group that it matches for. If the last group is called "Other Pages" and set to match anything, it will group all pages not collected higher on the list.

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2853563?hl=en